# Apache 2 + Tomcat 6 + Mod_jk: How can I close the port 8080?

Tags: apache2, tomcat6

I'd setup Apache 2.2 with Mod_Jk so that all Tomcat 6 pages is piped through Apache, port 80.  Everything work fine, all pages look good.

My question is: How can I close the port 8080 listened by Tomcat ?  Since right now all pages are served from port 80 by Apache, the port 8080 from Tomcat should not be accessed by end-user.  I don't have hardware or software firewall in the front to block port 8080.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Tomcats' server.xml file](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/server.html), you are going to want to comment out the [connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/connectors.html) that references port 8080.  Typically it would look something like:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment it out, restart and that should do it.

```
<!-- <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" /> -->
```

Comment: Will this still allow Apache to connect to tomcat?  Doesn't mod_jk connect via port 8080?

Comment: Andrew, This comments out the http connector, but the AJP one should still be open allowing mod_jk to connect to it.

Comment: thank you so much!!!
I entered to tomcat/conf/server.xml
Thank you !!!
but when I use http on port 8080 I can enter :/

Comment: to restart tomcat : service tomcat restart

Comment: Yes, you'll have to restart tomcat for it to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can disable it completely. But you can bind it to a specific address. I.E. 127.0.0.1, so it can only be accessed from localhost.

Here's how:

```
<Connector port="8080" address="127.0.0.1" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
maxThreads="15" minSpareThreads="2" maxSpareThreads="7"
enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
compression="on" compressionMinSize="0"
noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml" />
```

Comment: Probably the best route. Tomcat must listen on some port and this does that, albeit only on the loopback interface.